# Transpose every N rows in multiple columns into new columns

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I need help transposing every four rows of the following data frame

```
S1       P1     C     N     P
TQ001   101     1     6     9
TQ002   101     2     7     5
TQ003   101     3     5     3
TQ004   101     4     7     2
TQ005   102     2     8     1
TQ006   102     3     9     1
TQ007   102     4     0     4
TQ008   102     6     3     6
```

into

```
V1    V2    V3    V4      S1C   S2C   S3C   S4C   S1N   S2N   S3N   S4N   S1P   S2P   S3P   S4P
TQ001 TQ002 TQ003 TQ004     1     2     3     4     6     7     5     7     9     5     3     2
TQ005 TQ006 TQ007 TQ008     2     3     4     6     8     9     0     3     1     1     4     6
```

in R.

Answer (score 1):

Using `pivot_wider` from the `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(id = (row_number()-1) %% 4 + 1) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "id",
              values_from = c("S1", "C", "N", "P"),
              names_glue = "S{id}{.value}") %>% 
  select(V1 = S1S1, V2 = S2S1, V3 = S3S1, V4 = S4S1, everything(), -P1)
```

First, I add a column `id` that simply repeatedly counts from 1 to 4. Then, I use `pivot_wider` to make it into wide form, parsing the column names as you wanted using `names_glue`. Then, I (manually) rename the first 4 columns and drop the `P1` column that you didn't include in your expected output.

This gives:

```
  V1    V2    V3    V4      S1C   S2C   S3C   S4C   S1N   S2N   S3N   S4N   S1P   S2P   S3P   S4P
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 TQ001 TQ002 TQ003 TQ004     1     2     3     4     6     7     5     7     9     5     3     2
2 TQ005 TQ006 TQ007 TQ008     2     3     4     6     8     9     0     3     1     1     4     6
```

Input data:

```
df <- structure(list(S1 = c("TQ001", "TQ002", "TQ003", "TQ004", "TQ005", 
"TQ006", "TQ007", "TQ008"), P1 = c(101, 101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 
102, 102), C = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 6), N = c(6, 7, 5, 7, 8, 
9, 0, 3), P = c(9, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1, 4, 6)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: your example gives this error `Error in pivot_wider(., names_from = "id", values_from = c("S1", "C",  : 
  unused argument (names_glue = "S{id}{.value}")`

Comment: This is new functionality since tidyr 1.1.0. You can either update tidyr using `install.packages("tidyr")` or drop that argument and repair the names yourself.